# List of breakpoints in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

Is there a way to view a list of all breakpoints (enabled and disabled) set in a project in Visual Studio 2013 Pro?

It seems that [older versions have this feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/02ckd1z7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but I don't see a "Breakpoints" option under the debug menu (screenshot below) - I only see options for dealing with individual breakpoints once you're looking at them.

[image: VS2013 Debug menu]

Comment: DEBUG->Windows->Breakpoints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the list is still available

Debug / Windows / Breakpoints.

The shortcut is Ctrl-D, B

Comment: I figured it would be something rather obvious, and I was just missing it. Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl-D, B doesn't bring it up. Did you mean Alt+D, W, B? (Alternatively Alt+F9.)

Comment: @cp.engr: It worked for me just now (also, that's what the short-cut text says on the menu).  Note it's not Ctrl-D, Ctrl-B.  The second key is just B.

Comment: Are you using VS2013 Pro? My shortcut text says Alt+F9.

Comment: I'm using 2013 Ultimate, but I would be surprised if the shortcuts were different.

Comment: @VladFeinstein, ok, but he said that's what the shortcut *is*, not something custom.

Comment: @cp.engr - assignment of the shortcuts *may* depend on the typical usage that you chose while setting up the Studio for the first run.